# SPSS: How can I merge two variables so I can create one diagram and I won't get several

Tags: variables, statistics, diagram, spss

I have to analyze the data I collected from a questioner with SPSS. With one of my question people were able to choose two answers, which means I have two variables for this question. When I want to display the results in a diagram, SPSS will not let me combine both of these two answers. Instead it will create two diagrams for this one question. What do I need to do in order to combine the variables and to get one diagram that displays the overall result for this question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define this two variables as a "Multiple response set" first and then create a table from this set.

There are two ways this can be done:

### Variant A:

**Via Menu:**

- Analyze -> Tables -> Multiple Response Set
- Analyze -> Tables -> Custom Tables

The **syntax commands** for creating the response set would be: `MRSETS` and for producing the table `CTABLES`. Since the Ctables command can be quite complex, I recommend to generate it from the Custom Tables dialog box.

### Variant B:

**Via Menu:**

- Analyze -> Multiple Response -> Define Variable Sets
- Analyze -> Multiple Response ->Frequencies

**Via Syntax:**

```
MULT RESPONSE GROUPS=$setname (v1_a v1_b (1)) /* Assuming that "answer is chosen" is coded as "1". 
  /FREQUENCIES=$setname.
```

The differences between these two variants are discussed here: [Difference between Multiple Response Sets Under "Data" and "Analyze" Menus in SPSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25169937/3772141)